# Plotting a recursive function results in recursion limit exceeded exception

Tags: plotting, color, plot-themes

I am new to Mathematica and expecting some help.

I am trying to plot a discrete recursive function f[m, n] against m, for different values of n.

```
Show[Table[
  DiscretePlot[f[m, n], {m, 0, 80}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, 0},  
   PlotRange -> All], {n, 20, 100, 20}]]
```

I want each curve for n to be in a different color. Using `PlotTheme`colored them all in same color and the following gave me a recursion depth exceeded exception.

```
DiscretePlot[
 Evaluate[Table[f[m, n], {n, 20, 100, 20}]], {m, 0, 80}, 
 PlotTheme -> "DarkColor"]
```

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
Below is the simplified version of the code.

```
populationRatio[m_, n_] := a polynomial of m, n and a set of constants
population[m_, n_]      := populationRatio[m, n]*population[m-1, n]
population[0, n_]       := 1/(1+Sigma(k->n)[Pi(r->k)[populationRatio[r, n]]])
```

Comment: Please post `f`.

Comment: And your title has nothing to do with your problem.  Once you plot two functions, their colors will automatically differ.

Comment: @CarlWoll : It worked fine for me for non recursive functions.
I posted an edit, so that you can see the nature of the function. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : I have posted an edit. Thank you

Comment: Try to add this option: `PlotStyle -> Hue[n/100]`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch : It didn't work either. Thanks anyway

Comment: Probably you should use something like: `population[m_Integer, n_Integer] := rhs` and `population[0, n_Integer] := rhs`. The `Table` function is evaluating `f` with non-integer `m`.